# MySQL view generated using functions crash my app

Tags: mysql, function, view

I have a view in my database (MySQL) that ranks users. It is generated generated by functions:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW `users_ranks` AS select distinct `u`.`id` AS `id`, 
            `isUserVerified`(`u`.`id`) AS `verification`,
            `hasUserPicture`(`u`.`id`) AS `profile_picture`,
            `hasUserHobbies`(`u`.`id`) AS `hobbies`,
            ...
            ) AS total_value  

        from `users` `u`
```

this is an example of one of the functions called by the view:

```
CREATE FUNCTION hasUserPicture(user_id INT(10) UNSIGNED) RETURNS int(3)
            NO SQL
            DETERMINISTIC
            SQL SECURITY INVOKER
        BEGIN
            DECLARE hasPicture VARCHAR(191);

            SELECT
                users.profile_picture
                INTO
                hasPicture
                FROM
                users
                WHERE
                users.id = user_id
            LIMIT 1;

            IF hasPicture IS NULL or hasPicture = '' THEN
                RETURN 0;
            ELSE
                RETURN 4;
            END IF;
        END;
```

There are lots of function calls in my view (update takes 21sec). The problem is that the view is updated whenever a user modifies information and with a large number of users makes the whole app run out of memory and crash. How can I fix the problem? Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: A view works like a table, but it is not a table.  it is only a prepared SQL statement so how "view is continuously updated" and crashed the app? Probably there is other memory leak issue.

Comment: Hi Rakib, I might be wrong but I have noticed that my view takes 21sec to run with a large number of users. Whenever same data is modified it runs (new users added, pictures modified, etc). Maybe the word continuously is not used properly, English is not my first language. I am trying to understand if there is a better, faster way to achieve the same result.

Comment: In the function I don't see `users_ranks` view is being called. Can you please check user table if it's properly indexed or not?

Comment: Are you using `select` or `update`? if it takes quite long time, then run the query and check it's performance by optimizing and adding index.